# Logging/debugging the bash startup process

Tags: bash, logging, debug

My bash shell sometimes takes quite a while to start, probably due to a lot of stuff happening in my various dot files (e.g. .bash_profile, etc.). Is there any way to properly log the bash startup process, including function calls, time spent per task, and so on? I want to determine if there are any specific pieces of the startup that is slower than others.

Comment: Which O.S? I looked at RHEL and /var/log/boot.log maybe a place to start

Comment: Have a look at this, from stack overflow. I guess this whole question might just be a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5014823/how-to-profile-a-bash-shell-script

Comment: @ChrisLear Thanks for the link, obviously I did not search SO thoroughly enough. Yes, this should be marked as a duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

trace files opened on bash startup:

```
echo exit | strace bash -li |& grep '^open[a-z]*'
```

TL;DL see more in https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/334389/195113